# iOS - How to use NFC to recognize NFC tags?

Tags: ios, nfc, ios11, iphone7plus

According the the documentation by Apple, [CoreNFC framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc) now enables the iPhone 7 and 7Plus users to read NFC tags.

Is there anyone who tried it?
I am not able to find any demo for its working.

Please do support with the working code if possible.

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/hansemannn/iOS11-NFC-Example